# Get only properties count for java class

Tags: java, android, class, properties

Ok, so i have tried to get count of properties for class. I have seen two related questions, but they are not quite answering this.

[question one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016765/how-to-count-the-number-of-attributes-of-a-java-class)

[question two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685404/how-to-get-number-of-attributes-in-a-java-class)

problem with those two is, that

```
SomeClass.class.getDeclaredFields().length
```

and

```
SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethods().length
```

are not quite return what i would expect them to. I got sample class:

```
SomeClass {
    public static final int ONE = 1, TWO = 2, THREE = 3;

    public static int someMethodOne(){}
    public static int someMethodTwo(){}
}
```

Declared fields return 5 which according to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getdeclaredfields.htm) is wrong, and should be 3. Declared methods does not help either, because it returns 3, while there are only 2 declared methods. What is wrong with this?

Edit:
trying to do this with Java 8 & Android Studio

Comment: Prolly instant run inject some code - it would be easier if you will dump the names... use release without proguard ... [in "plain" java it works as expected](https://ideone.com/4PDenV)

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to make that kind of check on dev build?

Answer (score 2):

I get `3` and `2` as expected when I run the code below. If you get other values, you could also print the names of the fields and the methods (see below).

```
public class SomeClassChecker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SomeClass.class.getDeclaredFields().length);
        System.out.println(SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethods().length);

        for (Field field : SomeClass.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            System.out.println("field: " + field.getName());
        }

        for (Method method : SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            System.out.println("method: " + method.getName());
        }

    }

}
```

Java 8 & Eclipse. I get this (expected) output:

```
3
2
field: ONE
field: TWO
field: THREE
method: someMethodOne
method: someMethodTwo
```

Comment: Well i wanted this to be like check from inside of class i.e. `SomeClass.size();` however it returns wrong results for both cases (calling this from within a class and from external class).

I'm running Java 8 and AndroidStudio.

Comment: Strange that we get different results. Pls take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Sooo, i have printed names for both, and i got extra fields and methods: `field: $change` `field: serialVersionUID` `method: access$super`

Comment: Then I don't know. I don't understand where the fields and the constructor come from.